# Copy compiled gem to other computer, avoiding compiling again

Tags: ruby, rubygems, copy, rvm

Using RVM, how can I copy gems between two different computers? The gem is compiled and I want to avoid a compilation on the target machine.

I tried to copy the `.rvm/gems/ruby-x.x.x-pxxx@gemset/gems/gem_name` directory, and also the /bin and /cache, but in the target computer I can't see the gem in the `gem list` output.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to copy also the gem specification file you find in `.rvm/gems/ruby-x.x.x-pxxx@gemset/specifications/gem_name.gemspec`.

Keep in mind that the binary code could not run on the destination platform.

Comment: This doesn't work because the gem is compiled, and the target computer don't have the compiling dependencies. Should work for every other case though. - edited my question to reflect that

Answer (score 4):

You could use [gem-compiler](https://github.com/luislavena/gem-compiler) from [Luis Lavena](https://github.com/luislavena).

It should be as easy as (replace `<gem-*>` with actual gem information):

```
gem install gem-compiler
gem fetch <gem-name> --platform=ruby
gem compile <gem-name>-<gem-version>.gem
```

This commands will create the `*.gem` file for your platform which can be then moved to another machine and installed with `gem install --local <gem-file>`.

For more details check https://github.com/luislavena/gem-compiler#usage

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already had to, but it is not the case that I need to compile a gem to a different arch. Yet this information is valuable.